# Jquery object does not support property or method "values"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have jquery function that uses json to print some text from PHP. Its working fine in chrome, but i have this weird error in IE edge.
Object doesn't support property or method.

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#catlist ul" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            var list = ui.item.parent();
            var sorted = list.sortable( "toArray", { key: "catid[]" } );

            $.post( "catalog_ajax.php", { cmd: "reorder", sorted: sorted}, function( data ) {
                if (data.code=='OK') {

                } else {
                    alert('NOK');
                }
            },'json');

        }

    });
    $( "#catlist ul" ).disableSelection();

    $('.prodcat-remove').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ajaxurl = $(this).data('href');
        if (confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć?')) {
            $.getJSON(ajaxurl, function (response) {
                if (response.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        $('#catid_'+response.success).remove();
                    } else {
                        alert('Nie udało się usunąć kategorii, spróbuj ponownie później.');
                    }
                } else {
                        if (confirm("Uwaga!\n" + Object.values(response).join("\n"))) {
                            $.getJSON(ajaxurl + '&force=1', function (response) {
                                if (response.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
                                    if (response.success) {
                                        $('#catid_'+response.success).remove();
                                    } else {
                                        alert('Nie udało się usunąć kategorii, spróbuj ponownie później.');
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    alert("Nie można usunąć katalogu\n" + Object.values(response).join("\n"));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Its breaking on the line

```
if(confirm("Uwaga!\n"+Object.values(response).join("\n")))
```

I have no idea whats the problem...

Comment: `Object.values` is not supported on IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.values is unsupported in many browsers - you can use .map to get an array of all the values:

```
 var vals = Object.keys(countries).map(function(key) {
        return countries[key];
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation of [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) you will see that there is no support for Internet Explorer but it has support for Chrome/Firefox/Edge

Instead you can use

```
Object.keys(response).map(k=>response[k])
```

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is supported starting from IE9